# Writing Mysql and Php code in wordpress Posts

Tags: settings-api

I am on wordpress and i am writing php or mysql code in a post but finally when i hit publish it gives an Server Error : 500 , i also trying putting my code under [code] [/code] tags nothing happened but when i remove my codes and hit publish then it's working

Any idea guys Waiting for help

Comment: Are you trying to display code or actually run code?

Answer (score 1):

With a stock WordPress install, you cannot insert server side code like PHP directly into a post, only HTML-compatible text. Using the [code][/code] shortcode only outputs what is inside as PRE and CODE elements of HTML, useful for showing code to your readers. In general, it is a bad idea to put code directly into a post.

Thank being said, there are several plugins that will give you this capability. See the following:

- [Shortcode Exec PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/)
- [Allow PHP in Posts and Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/)
- [WP exec PHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-exec-php/)

Comment: No problem, go ahead and accept the answer if it worked for you so others know how to embed PHP as well.